Show that if $\limsup_{j\to\infty}\frac{j(a_{j+1}-a_{j})}{a_{j}}<0$, then $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_{j}$ converge
Problem
Suppose that $(a_{j})_{j=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of positive numbers for which $a_{j+1}/a_{j} \to 1$, so that D'Alembert's test gives no information. Show that if
$$\limsup_{j\to\infty}\frac{j(a_{j+1}-a_{j})}{a_{j}}<0,$$
then, $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_{j}$ converges.
This problem is Exercise 4.2.13 from A Course in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 1 (D. J. H. Garling). The previous exercise, Exercise 4.2.12, covered Kummer's convergence test, which is a test that looks like this.
Kummer's test Suppose that $(a_{j})_{j=0}^{\infty}$ and $(c_{j})_{j=0}^{\infty}$ are sequences of positive real numbers. If
$$\limsup_{j\to\infty}\left(\frac{c_{j+1}a_{j+1}}{a_{j}}-c_{j}\right)<0,$$
then $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_{j}$ converges.
Exercise 4.2.13 says that it deals with a special case of kummer's test, I'm not sure how to connect it to kummer's test. Even the smallest hint would be very helpful.

$\frac{j(a_{j+1}-a_{j})}{a_{j}}=\frac{ja_{j+1}}{a_{j}}-j$ and $(j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of positive real numbers

@MAPelto But, isn't it a contradiction to have $c_{j} = j, c_{j+1} = j$?

Dang I misread $\frac{c_{j+1}a_{j+1}}{a_{j}}$ as $\frac{c_{j}a_{j+1}}{a_{j}}$, subscripts are small. How about use $j<j+1$. There done.

This is false: for $a_j = 1/j,$ we get $ j \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j} - j = \frac{j^2}{j+1} - j = \frac{-j}{j+1} \to -1.$ You need the limsup to be $< - 1$, in which case M A Pelto's argument applies (in Kummer's it's fine for the $c_j$ to only eventually all be positive (why?)).

@stochasticboy321 good point. Since $\limsup_{j\to\infty} \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}=\lim_{j\to\infty} \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}=1$, the result should be about if either $\limsup_{j\to\infty}\frac{j(a_{j+1}-a_{j})}{a_{j}}<-1$ or (equivalently) $\limsup_{j\to\infty}\frac{(j+1)a_{j+1}-ja_{j}}{a_{j}}<0$.
